# Querying Bookings API using Microsoft Graph isnt working

Tags: http, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I am trying to use Microsoft flow to retrieve Microsoft Bookings data. Im doing this by using the HTTP with azure AD connector. I have set up all permissions. it was working perfectly fine before till yesterday the connector said i'm unauthorized to retrieve the data. i can't even hit https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/page_id/appointments anymore. Is there some issue with Microsoft ??? or is there an issue on my side.i’ve used graph explorer and im able to successfully retrieve the bookings api.  could someone provide some feedback as this is becoming business critical as i need to obtain the data for reporting. Or maybe guide me on how i can retrieve an access token that never expires. It would be much appreciated if someone can really help me out. I've attached a screenshot of my flow failing. 
[Screenshot of HTTP with Azure AD failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6AMq.png) . I've just also found out that i can query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta but i cant hit the BookingBusinesses api

[Screen shot of https://graph.microsoft.com/beta working using connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kEuI.png)

What i have already tried:

  Deleted the connection and created it again

  Created a connection using another account

  Created App registrations and used the Client_id, tenant_id and client_secret to Created a connection using the HTTP request. but still doesn't work

[Screenshot of HTTP Request Connector, but this still failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEYR7.png)

[App registration Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPiE9.png)

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Comment: H @rainer, i have added a couple more screenshots and a bit more detail to my answer

Comment: Hi, has this problem been solved ? If still show error message, could you please provide a screenshot of the permissions which you added to your app in App registration ? like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph2mn.png)

Comment: Hi , here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPiE9.png

Comment: Also i did get the access token using the HTTP POST request. https://i.stack.imgur.com/61yqN.png. But when i use HTTP GET. i get an Unauthorized error. i've found that the access token length given in the flow is a lot shorter than the one provided on graph explorer so am i doing some thing wrong?Also here is the screenshot of where i get unauthorized message when i query bookings https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoMXA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, I test it by "Invoke an HTTP request" first but as I'm not familiar with this action, I didn't request it success. But we can also use "HTTP" action in microsoft flow to get the access token and use the access token to do the request as you mentioned in comments.

The reason for you failed to use the access token to request the graph api is you set the grant_type as `client_credentials` when you request for the access token. Since the permissions you added are "**delegated**" type but not "**application**" type, so we can not use "**client_credentials**" grant to get the access token. We need to use "**password**" as the grant_type (shown as below screenshot).
[image]

Then use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the response of the "HTTP" request above to get the access token. And use the access token to request the graph api.
[image]

Comment: Hi @huryShen so i gave it a go but i got Invalid Grant: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the Directory , I am putting in my email address and password that i use to login to azure. How do i check that i am in the directory ? . i had the same problem when i was trying to get this to work in postman as well.

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed It seems your account doesn't exist in azure directory, is it a guest account in Azure ? Or native account like xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com ?

Comment: My account does exist which is what i'm confused about . My user type is Member and source is Windows Server AD. Does is matter what the user type is ?

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed Does your account be assigned "Global administrator" role ?

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed I'm not sure if Windows server AD will affect it, could you please create another user account(xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com) on Azure portal and assign "Global administrator" role to it, and then use this account to test.

Comment: should i also exists in the owners list within the app registration?

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed No, I think it's unnecessary to be the owner of the app, "Global administrator" role is enough.

Comment: I dont know if it's a problem but is it because i have multi factor authentication ?.I have DUO turned on, would this be causing my problem?  Sorry i don't have right to create a new account as Global Admin, but i can get that checked next week monday.

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed As far as I know, MFA could affect it.

Comment: im also getting AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password. I checked my sign in events and i see it fails , but im entering exactly the same login and password as i do for azure and graph explorer

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed May I know if your company enabled MFA a few days ago ?

Comment: we actually had MFA enabled in our country a last year so we have been using DUO since then.  i also just created a free azure portal account using my existing hotmail account. A added my company email to the directory and made it a global admin. And tried using that. Still doesnt work. I dont know if my format is wrong? You can checkout the link for my screenshot to confirm or if MFA is. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeNXU.png

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed You added your company email to the new Azure AD ? It seems this email account is as a guest in the new AD. Could you please create a new native account(xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com) in the new AD and use this account username and password to do the grant flow to get the access token ?

Comment: Sorry if this a really dumb question but where can i go and create a xxx@onmicrosoft.com account?. When i try create a new through http://login.microsoftonline.com/ i only get an option to create one with an outlook or hotmail domain.

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed You need to go to [azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) and login with your new hotmail account. Then refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-users-azure-active-directory) to create a user, try to use this user account to do password grant flow in logic app.

Comment: @hurySchen Sorry for the late reply but was trying to get this sorted with my IT department. So i finally got my access token. and ill accept your answer as it was correct :). Just another question  how can i get access to other booking pages through the api what do i need to do?? i added myself as staff member to the pages but i still cant see them in the api

Comment: @ShafeelMohammed I'm sorry that I don't know much about booking pages. I just know how to get the access token and do the authentication. You can create another post on stack overflow and someone else may help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the flow connector lost its refresh token or something to that effect. you may need to just refresh your flow connector. either by switching accounts or smoething or deleting the azure ad connector and reconnecting it.

give that a try

Comment: HI @alphaz18, i've given that a go but it still doesnt for when i hit the BookingBusinesses API,  But what i found out was that i can hit https://graph.microsoft.com/beta but when i try hit BookingBusinesses i get a a 401 Unauthorized error coming up. I have tried creating App registration in azure and grabbing the client_id, tenant_id and client_secret and using HTTP connector instead but i still get the same error unfortunately. It's just i did have permissions before and i don't know why it dosnt work anymore, and im not sure how my permissions have dropped and where

Comment: Not sure what happened but you probably need to add api permissions on that app registration. probably have to go to app reg  -> api permissions -> add a permission -> microsoft graph api -> delegated permissions -> search for bookings. depending on what operation you'll need one or more of the 4 permissions from bookings.read.all to readwrite.all or.. bookingappointments.readwriteall and/or manage.all